# Nested Pan with Hammer.js

Tags: javascript, events, hammer.js

I try to have two sorts of pan on my listing :

-One vertical pan on the listing wrapper for init a pull to refresh action

-One horizontal pan on each rows of listing for display delete/edit actions

I have used the requireFailure method of Hammer.js for not triggered the 2 pans at the same time.

Pans events work normally, but after horizontal pan on 2 rows, my vertical pan stop to work..

**Here a snippet of my problem :**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset=utf-8 />
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.js"></script>
 <script type="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
 ul {
  list-style: none;

 }
 li {
  height: 50px;
  background: #F2F6F8;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items : center;
 }
</style>
<body>
  <ul id='listing'>
   <li class="row-listing">
    Test Test    
   </li>
    <li class="row-listing">
    Test Test    
   </li>
    <li class="row-listing">
    Test Test    
   </li>
   <li class="row-listing">
    Test Test    
   </li>
    <li class="row-listing">
    Test Test    
   </li>
   <li class="row-listing">
    Test Test    
   </li>
  </ul>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 
 this.hammer = new Hammer.Manager(document.getElementById("listing"));
    
 var panMax =  100;
 var pos;
 
 //add pan event
 this.panV = new Hammer.Pan({threshold: 10, direction : 24});
 
 this.hammer.add(this.panV);

 
 
 this.hammer.on('pandown panup', function(e){
  
  if($('#listing').scrollTop() <= 5 ) {
   
    var percent = (100 / 60) * e.deltaY;
     pos  = ( 60 / 100) * 100 + percent -50;
     pos  = Math.min(panMax, pos);

   $('#listing').css('transform','translate3d(0, ' + (pos < 0  ? 0 : pos ) + 'px, 0)');
   
  }
  
 });

 this.hammer.on('panend', function(e){
  $('#listing').css('transform','translate3d(0, 0px, 0)');

 })



 var _this = this;
 console.log(_this);
 $('.row-listing').each(function(){
     
  var rowsListingHammer = new Hammer.Manager(this);
  var panH    =  new Hammer.Pan({threshold: 10, direction : 6});
  
  rowsListingHammer.add(panH);
   
  var pos;
  var panMin   = -200;
  var panMax   = 15;
  var row    = this;
  var $swipeWrapper = $(row).find('.swipeActions'); //wrapper wich contains actions
  var $el    = $(row);//row to translate
  
  rowsListingHammer.on('panleft panright', function(e) {
   
   var percent = (100 / 60) * e.deltaX;
   pos   = ( 60 / 100) * 100 + percent;
   pos   = Math.max(pos,panMin);
   
   if(pos > 0) {
    pos = 0;
   }
   
   $el.css('transform','translate3d(' + pos + 'px,  0, 0)');
   $swipeWrapper.css('transform','translate3d(' + pos + 'px,  0, 0)');
   
  });
  
    
  rowsListingHammer.on('panend', function(e){
   $el.css('transform','translate3d(0,  0, 0)');  
  });

  _this.hammer.get('pan').requireFailure(panH);

 });

    
</script>
</html>
```

Thanks you for help.